# Spring security role-based authorisation best practices

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

So I basically have a controller method with a PreAuthorize annotation. By default the method will return all projects. The method signature also includes an optional query string (blank query means retrieve all records). 
The issue is that if the logged in user is only supposed to view/manage his/her own records, the query string needs to include a filter in it such as "clientId:2". 
Now to do that, I was thinking of using the Principal object to retrieve the logged in user and check if he/she is a client as well, then I update the query by adding the required filter to it. 
I am just not sure if this is the best approach for this type of issues.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MANAGE_ALL') OR hasAuthority('VIEW_ALL') OR hasAuthority('MANAGE_OWN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> list(Principal principal, @RequestParam(value = "query", required = false, defaultValue = "") String query) {

//If a client is logged in, he/she will have the MANAGE_OWN authority so will need to update the query string to include clientId:<logged-in-client-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather move the @PreAuthorize to an application service.

```
class SomeApplicationService {

     UserService userService;
     SecurityService securityService;

     @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MANAGE_ALL') OR hasAuthority('VIEW_ALL') OR  hasAuthority('MANAGE_OWN')")
     public List<Project> getProjects(String clientId) {
        User currentUser = userService.getLoggedInUser();
        if(securityService.canManageAllProjects(currentUser))
            //get all projects or projects of clientId
        else if(securityService.canManageOwnProjects(currentUser))
            //get own projects, ignore clientId
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply wolverine. Your solution is tightly coupled with the userService and the securityService. My services (including the projectService) are used internally by other services as well as system scripts. I like, however, the use of securityService at the controller level instead. What do you think?

Comment: I consider UserService and SecurityService as shared services, which can be injected into other application services. I don't like to use SecurityService in controller because the application logic leaks out of application layer. If you don't want to have UserService and SecurityService in app service then you could have two Application Service methods like `getOwnProjects` and `getAllProjects` and have two different URLs for them in the controller layer.